# Desktop Configuration: More than 32GB RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade, desktop-computer

For Particle Simulations, I considered upgrading my desktop PC. I would be willing to invest into 64GB of RAM, but as I have checked, all desktop motherboards have maximum memory limits of 32GB.

What options do I have, please, if I wish to build cost effective desktop solution with 64+GB of RAM?

I understand, that I can not request to advice particular products recommendation, but I ask for an advice in general: what kind of technology to go for, is there anything available on market? Do I need to move to server solutions, or are there desktop solutions for me too?

Comment: This looks like a shopping recommendation question.  Such questions are off topic here; see the [FAQ#dontask] for details.  See also this [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @DragonLord, hi Dragon. Not at all. You do not have to recommend me any particular products. I wish to know to advise a way, or a technology in general, I should look for. So again, not particular product, but a general advice on what kind of technology to look for.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Build a [workstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workstation#Current), not a consumer-grade desktop.

Comment: @iglvzx: hi. Yeah, I considered that already, but then I am getting to the price level of 3.000+ EUR investment. I hoped there is cheaper way  to go.

Comment: No, not really. You get what you pay for. We sell this sort of level of hardware as servers, and the price point is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider server motherboards [like these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007733%20600038383&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=302&description=&hisInDesc=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&AdvancedSearch=1&srchInDesc=). Server motherboards can support a lot more RAM, though that RAM will be ECC and, as a result, will be much more expensive than ordinary RAM. Also, you're likely to see very sharp price spikes towards largest-RAM sticks compared to smaller ones.

Comment: Was your answer truncated, and is it formatted properly?

Comment: it's ok, just too short

Comment: @jet: Hi Jet + 1 and thank you for you answer. **What kinds of motherboards are those?** Are they server motherboards, or workstation onses? I see, some of them have capacity of almos 200 GB. They are mostly 2 CPUs motherboards, which can add additional performance to the computations. **Did you pick http://www.newegg.com just randomly**, or is is exceptional place to buy HW from, for some reason?

Comment: These are server MB hence dual CPUs. NewEgg is one of my favourite, picked it up because of nice pictures of the products and lots user's reviews, you can see

Comment: I found something even better on NewEgg. There are [single CPU motherboards for the newest Intel 2011 socket](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007627+600238945+600008642&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=280&description=&hisInDesc=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&AdvancedSearch=1&srchInDesc=).

Comment: As I believe, my question has been answered here, I am marking this response as the *Accepted Answer*.

Comment: Link-only answers are no-no on SU due to possible future link rot. Please include applicable information in your answer.

Comment: The sad thing you'll most likely pay a fortune for even 192Gb, let alone more.